# SQL Concatenate all values in column B that have same value in column A for all values in column A

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, string-aggregation

I am running PostgreSQL 12.4. I have a relatively large table like the following where column 1 and 2 are both of `character varying` type:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Column 1      |     Column 2     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         foo         |         X        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         foo         |         Y        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         foo         |         Z        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         bar         |         A        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         bar         |         B        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         bar         |         C        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I would like to create something like the following:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Column 1      |     Column 2     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         foo         |      X, Y, Z     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         bar         |      A, B, C     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `string_agg`:

```
select column1, string_agg(column2, ', ')
from table_name
group by column1
```

You can find more info [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/).

Comment: @Xela you can thank me by upvoting and accepting the answer;>